# Lambda function skipping SNS publish call

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

im currently trying to send a push notification from AWS Lambda but the following code is getting skipped in my function as i tried to output something within and its not showing.
Please help me

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
const sns = new AWS.SNS();
AWS.config.region = 'ap-southeast-1'

exports.handler = async event => {
  const params = {
    TableName: "Items" // The name of your DynamoDB table
  };
  try {
    // Utilising the scan method to get all items in the table
    const data = await documentClient.scan(params).promise();
    var allItems = data.Items;
    allItems.forEach(async function (item){
        const tempItem = item;
        var endDate = new Date(tempItem.endDate);
        var today = new Date();
        today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        var currentDaysLeft = endDate - today;
        if (currentDaysLeft < 0)
        {
            currentDaysLeft = 0;
        }
        
        // convert JS date milliseconds to number of days
        currentDaysLeft = Math.ceil(currentDaysLeft / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 
        
        if (tempItem.durationLeft != currentDaysLeft){
            tempItem.durationLeft = currentDaysLeft;
        }
        
        const message =  tempItem.username + "'s " + tempItem.title + " is expiring in " + tempItem.durationLeft + " days." ;

        const msgparams = {
          Message: message,
          TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-1:xxxxxxxxx:xxxxx'
        };
        var publishPromise = sns.publish(msgparams).promise();
        
    });
    return;
  } catch (e) {
    return {
      body: e
    };
  }
};
```

I have tested that the for each loop runs correctly based on the number of items returned and that the data from the scan is all indeed correct, but the publish part is not running

this is my code for firebase messaging service

```
public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
        {
            base.OnMessageReceived(message);
            string messageBody = string.Empty;

            if (message.GetNotification() != null)
            {
                messageBody = message.GetNotification().Body;
            }

            // NOTE: test messages sent via the Azure portal or AWS SNS portal will be received here
            else
            {
                messageBody = message.Data.Values.First();
            }

            // convert the incoming message to a local notification
            SendLocalNotification(messageBody);
        }
```

Comment: can you please add your full lambda code?

Comment: edited my post to show my lambda code

Comment: await missing before `sns.publish(msgparams).promise();` ?

Comment: i added the await keyword but its still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return all the sns publish promise and collect them in an array and use await on all the promise array.

```
const publishPromises = allItems.map(function (item){
......
return sns.publish(msgparams).promise();
});

await Promise.all(publishPromises);
```

Comment: this is a step in the right direction since the push notifications are sent through, but im only getting 1 push notification when there are supposed to be 6 in total. now im left wondering if this is the limitation of the code or AWS SNS

Comment: You mean to say allItems length is 6 and publishPromises length in 1 ?
You can add some debug statements to check the size of both of above mentioned arrays and add one log statement inside map function to check how many time it was executed.

Comment: i just did the testing and the size of publishPromises is 6 and the logs show 6 log statements but the phone im using only received one notification. im using an android with API 27 if that matters

Comment: You can add one sqs subscription to your SNS and validate how many messages you received there. There you should receive 6 messages.

Comment: the sqs subscription does indeed show 6 messages sent, but number of messages received 0

Comment: ive edited the post to show my code for receiving messages inside firebase messaging service

Comment: okay i figured out the problem, in my notificationManager.Notify i accidentally hard coded the id so the push notifications were just replacing each other and it just looked like i was only receiving one notification. Thanks for your code snippet in helping me send the notifications in the first place.